# What printer offers the best quality?

Tags: print-design, patterns, copy-protection

I am not sure if this is the best place to post this but it seems like the best from what i've found.
I need to print stickers for identifying my company assets and I'd like to put security features on them like this:[image]

My printer can't print it clearly, so I'm looking for one that can. Any help will be much appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: Hi default, Welcome to Graphic Design.

Comment: errr.. stickers can be removed. -- What benefit do you see to having a *sticker* with security features? It seems to me using a sticker would directly work *against* any security.

Comment: @Scott security stickers exist

Comment: I realize that. But in general they are *exceptionally* cost prohibitive for anyone but major corporations. And they aren't traditionally used as "identifiers". Most often they are used as tamper evidence. In which case, I'm sure you could outright [purchase some security stickers](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hollographic+security+stickers&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) rather than manufacturing them yourself.

Comment: Surely security stickers aren't as expensive as home printer ink at 80% page coverage, which is what that image looks like it would require.

Comment: I don't know about the security aspect, but the reason why your "printer can't print it clearly" could be that it's not vector or that it consists of more than one ink. Depending on the size of this pattern it should be possible to print as vector graphics in one ink.

Answer (score 2):

If you can buy a normal printer that can print this, anyone can.

A "security" measure should be at least expensive to make in a short run. This is if you are a company you could let's say, spend 1000 dollars to print 2000 copies of your "security" paper. It will cost you 50 cents each.

For a random person to try to forge it for one or 10 copies, it will cost 1000 or 100 dollars each, which could dissuade them to do it.

Using a digital printer to print it directly makes you be able to print just one... so it is not a good strategy.

For example, some hologram manufacturers have strict control on who's logo they make a run of stickers, so no one can come and claim they want a random logo made. Making holograms needs expensive and specialized equipment, so only serious companies do it, so it is harder to forge unless it is an organized crime endeavor.

Try at least to print a base of your background on a different system than an inkjet printer. Sheeted offset is the cheapest one, but still one option.

I am going to steal Wolff's comment.

In order to print sharper as your printer can, make the image in vectors and force the colors to print just one color.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the printer that will make the difference; but, the printing process.

The finest detail printing process is gravure.

The most difficult image to reproduce is a hologram.

The most difficult pattern to reproduce is the Euro currency "Eurion" pattern since scanners have been programmed to ignore the pattern.

The most difficult colours to reproduce are metallic inks.

Use any of these in combination to discourage counterfeit copies of your work.

Comment: Iridescent inks I would say, they are different than just metallic inks.

Comment: @Rafael Yes. Add it to the list. There must be others too such as metameric pair failures, unique/scarce materials, processes, etc. Thanx.